# Word VBA, Prevoius code getting in way

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've written a word vba macro for someone. I've saved the file both as a .dotm and .docm file. When I open the file on his computer I see there are a bunch of macros in there that I didn't write!

Even sometimes when I open one of my own word macros on my own computer a see a bunch of code I didn't write, normally under the "normal" tab:
[image]

The problem is sometimes the previous code inside the word document can cause errors for the new code.

This doesn't occur for other types of projects. VBA for Excel, powerpoint, access, ....

**Question1:** Why is that code  there?

**Question2:** How can I send a word macro file to someone without having to worry about the previous code getting in the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[David Zemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1467082/david-zemens) has supplied you with a solid answer, however to add a bit of additional information to explain this behavior:
The **Normal** template fires upon the opening/closing/alteration of ***any*** document (*global behavior*). As a result, if you add some macro code to the **Normal** template, you can expect it to happen even when you open a blank Word document.

To avoid this, either don't place code in **Normal** that you don't want to happen *globally*, or follow one of the alternatives in David's answer. My guess is you want macros that only link to **certain** documents, in which case you should place them outside of **Normal**, as to not get conflicting behavior. I personally like AddIns better for global behavior if that is in fact what you are looking for, as they will not produce any strange behavior with existing code in **Normal**.

Answer (score 3):

> Question1: Why is that code there?

`Normal.dotm` is the standard document *template*.

https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Change-the-Normal-template-Normaldotm--06de294b-d216-47f6-ab77-ccb5166f98ea?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE

> The Normal.dotm template opens whenever you start Microsoft Office Word 2007, and it includes default styles and customizations that determine the basic look of a document.

When you open a blank document, I think by default Word will use this template and so any macros in that Normal.dotm file will persist in the "new" document, and further the `Normal.dotm` will appear in the VBE.  (This actually can be similar to Excel if you have a `Personal.xlsb` file, although this is not present by default in Excel)

> Question2: How can I send a word macro file to someone without having to worry about the previous code getting in the way?

You can always manually remove any unwanted/unneeded modules from the file, before you send to another.

Alternatively, the better way of distributing macros would be in a document template or an Add-in file.

Alternatively, you can export the module code as a text file and the other user can import it.

Comment: Great answer :) might be worth mentioning the global nature of **Normal** as compared to how document templates are fired?

Comment: @DonkeyKong feel free to revise/update my answer with that information, I do not do very much development in Word so I'm not as familiar with that as I am with PPT or XLS.

Comment: Thank for the answer. But its not the extra code on my side that's causing the problem, but rather the code on the receivers side. Even when he opens a blank word file there is already a bunch code there.

Comment: @behnam One moment, I can explain.